# What is this foreign language registry key?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry

Does anyone recognize this?

[image: Foreign registry key]

It's under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software (and HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-....\Sodtware) on an English WinXP machine.
I don't remember ever having installed something called 'PC Sync', definitely not the [LapLink product with the same name](http://www.laplink.com/index.php/individuals/file-transfer-remote-management/pcsync) (and no synching software anyway).
There are no other keys named 'PC Sync' in the registry.

Added:

It's Korean, Franks comment is correct - Google translate now converts it to:
Local AppWizard-generated application.

Googling for *Local AppWizard*, I find these [two](http://www.codefighter.com/registry.html) [pages](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VC/microsoft.public.vc.mfc/2007-07/msg00138.html) which seem to suggest that they may be leftovers from an installation program (written in C?) that failed to call 'SetRegistryKey("appname"); in InitInstance.' ?

Comment: that looks like the Korean alphabet, but sometimes fonts hide the identifying characteristics.

Comment: Copy the text and put it into Google Translate for further insights.

Comment: AppWizard is used by Microsoft to describe Visual Studio 6.0 (pre .net) MFC applications, so thats one potential option. I'd also look at packagers and installer systems

Comment: You can use ProcessMonitor from SysInternals to log all registry access. If you set a filter to this key, then you can check which application(s) access the registry key.

Comment: @Werner Never knew Processmonitor could do that. Don't know if it helps though because the keys are probably leftovers from an installation (they're empty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pnuts hit the nail on the head.
I have an old Samsung (pre-smartphone era) and I (not so long ago) installed its software in order to backup the phone list to the PC (so synching software indeed).

Frank is probably also right that it is pre-Dotnet.